# refreshControl webview react native not working on android (ios run perfect)

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

where ever i try to scroll top inside the webview it reload .
no matter in i am at the top of webview or in medel or end .

in ios only in the top it relaod

hear is my code look like

```
  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}
    refreshControl={
      
    }>
    <WebView
      key={thiskey}
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width }}

      onLoadStart={() => { }}
      onLoadProgress={() => { }}
      onLoad={() => {
        console.log('onLoad');
      }}
      thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={true}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      source={{
        uri: DOMAIN_URL + [route.params?.showOne] + '?webview=2',
      }}
    </View>
```

i need the code run on android like ios